# "На мысе" или "на мысу"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильнее сказать: "на мысе" или "на мысу"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обе формы указываются в словарях как литературные. Однако если слово **мыс** входит в состав географического названия, то употребляется форма '*на мысе*': на мысе Доброй Надежды, на мысе Горн и т.п.